# UIView background image gets squashed

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-3.x

In my iPhone app I have a UIView with a tiled background image created via `view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IndexCard.png"]];`

On my iOS3.1 device, when the view gets resized, the background image gets squashed - i.e. it tiles the same number of times but the height of each tile is reduced. Instead I would like each tile to stay the same size but the number of repeats to adjust according to the new view size. If I clear the background and then reset it the problem gets fixed, but that seems like a particular innefficient solution to the problem. On the iOS4.3 simulator it works correctly.

Here's the original image - 12 lines:

[image: The original image]

Here's what I'm seeing when I resize the view - it still has 12 lines:

[image: What I'm seeing - the image is squashed]

Whereas here's what I'd really like to see - the background would be cropped to 5 lines:

[image: What I want to see - the image cropped]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution:

```
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
// instead of the default UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
```

Answer (score 1):

The view's `backgroundColor` property is assigning a color (or pattern) to the `CALayer` that is the basis for drawing the view. You can change the CALayer's properties by addressing the `layer` property of the view.

Looking through the [CALayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) I see that there's a property called `contentsGravity` that:

> Determines how the receiver's contents
>   are positioned within its bounds.

It indicates that:

> The possible values for `contentsGravity` are shown in “[Contents Gravity Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Contents_Gravity_Values)”.  The default value is [`kCAGravityResize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCAGravityResize).

That explains why your image is being squished like that: by default it's resizing the image. Taking a look at the other *Contents Gravity Values* there are a couple of options that are likely best for you:

> `kCAGravityTop`: The content is horizontally centered at the top-edge of the bounds rectangle.
>
> `kCAGravityCenter`: The content is horizontally and vertically centered in the bounds rectangle.
>
> 'kCAGravityBottom': The content is horizontally centered at the bottom-edge of the bounds rectangle.

I'd guess that `kCAGravityTop` is probably what you're looking for, so you'd set your view's layer's `contentsGravity` like this:

```
view.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop;
```